# Itext pdf - text alignment to right

Tags: java, itext

I am using Itext PDF API to generate a pdf. I am trying to get some text to be aligned to the right-hand side of the pdf. I have tried the manual method of spacing but is not working for some reason (Code shown below). Meanwhile, if there is a way of doing it dynamically that would be great, please!

```
String dest = "\\location\\";
    PdfWriter writer;

        writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        // Creating a PdfDcoument
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Creating a Document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        // Creating a String
        String para1 = "TEXT";

        //Spacing length
        while (para1.length() < 50) {

              para1 = " " + para1;

            }


        //Creating Paragraphs
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(para1);

        //paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        //Adding Paragraphs to document
        document.add(paragraph1);

        // Closing the document
        document.close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph` in `itext7` has method `setTextAlignment`. I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
...                 
            paragraph1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);    
...
```

Comment: Indeed. +1 for this good answer to a strange (and very trivial) question

Comment: Thank you mistyk. +1. @BrunoLowagie, I don't really see how strange or trivial the question is. Thanks for the remark though....

Answer (score 2):

I'm using com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10 and it looks like the stuff has moved around a bit.

```
    paragraph1.setAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT)
```